# FFMPEG H264 split demux a stream video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming, video-conversion

I've got an H264 video (Stored in an 264 file). 
With ffplay i see that:

```
[NULL @ 00000000003454a0] start time for stream 0 is not set in estimate_timings _from_pts
[mpeg @ 0000000000344560] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Audio: mp2, 0 channels): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpeg, from 'int_max.264':
 Duration: 03:37:45.30, start: 35437.583167, bitrate: 6574 kb/s
   Stream #0:0[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 0 channels
   Stream #0:1[0x1e1]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 704x576, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
   Stream #0:2[0x1e2]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 704x576, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
   Stream #0:3[0x1e0]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 704x576, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
   Stream #0:4[0x1e3]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 704x576, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
```

Is it possible to split this file in four single files h264,one file for any stream ?? 
Can I do this with ffmpeg? How is this possible? 
Can I give me some advice?

I've got FFmpeg and x264 available. I'm happy to use either the FFmpeg command line, or my own program linked against ffmpeg of x264 libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`-map`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) to select your desired streams, and `-codec copy` (or the `-c copy` alias) to use [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode instead of re-encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i input \
-map 0:v:0 -codec copy output0 \
-map 0:v:1 -codec copy output1 \
-map 0:v:2 -codec copy output2 \
-map 0:v:3 -codec copy output3
```

`0:v:3` refers to: select first input (`0`), select video stream type (`v`), select the fourth video stream (`3`). Note that `ffmpeg` starts counting from 0 for `-map`, so that is why `3` is the fourth stream.

The above example, in your case, is the same as:

```
ffmpeg -i input \
-map 0:1 -codec copy output0 \
-map 0:2 -codec copy output1 \
-map 0:3 -codec copy output2 \
-map 0:4 -codec copy output3
```

...but I generally find the first method more flexible.